# Passive voice of "He won the race"

Tags: active-voice

I came up with two versions:

1. The race was won by him.
2. He was the winner of the race.

Are these both correct? Is there any difference?

Comment: No, the second one is not correct.The point of passivising is to invert the object and make it the subject.As you can see, only the first sentence does that.All three sentences basically say the same thing, but (1) only satisfies your query.

Answer (score 0):

Passive voice is something when the subject is acted on by the verb. Or in other words, subjects doesn't necessarily have to be mentioned, but if required in any case, it goes at last. In your sentence, first one is correct since the subject is at last. But the second one is absolutely wrong and you have guessed why!